# Can't see IIS-FTP logs in event viewer

Tags: iis, ftp, windows-server-2016

I heard there is a log that i can view in the event viewer that comes from the IIS-FTP source with the event id 13.
This event id indicates failed logon attempt to an FTP server (running with IIS 10 and logging is enabled).
For some reason the FTP server doesn't seem to generate these events to an evtx file but only to a text file located in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\FTPSVC.

How can i enable the logging to evtx file format and where can i view these events in the event viewer?

Comment: There is no such a thing. If you are trying to monitor activities of your IIS server, then unfortunately you need to read the separate log files. This applies to many Microsoft or third party products, as no one should flood the event log for application specific log entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the IIS FTP (text) logs with the "Log Parser" tool from Microsoft to evtx, and then you can open that evtx using the event viewer management console.
Log Parser works with queries, this is an example query to transform them to evtx

```
SELECT *
FROM 'C:\Path\To\Your\FTP\Log\Files\u_ex*.log'
WHERE (Fields(1) LIKE 'FTP')
INTO 'C:\Path\To\Your\Output\Folder\output.evtx'
USING SELECT *
```

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659

To take it a bit further, you can also ingest it directly into the Windows Event Logs Using a custom event log source and logparser.